# Using VB script to run VBA Macros and save the excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to run a macro from a * *.vbs* file. You can find the code below. The module runs with no issue (this has been tested). But workbook is not saved. I tried adding `ThisWorkbook.Save` into the module itself but it causes an error and tells me that my file is *ReadOnly*. To clarify, I want to know how to save the workbook after running a macro through VBScript.

```
Option Explicit

'On Error Resume Next 'Comment-out for debugging

ExcelMacro

Sub ExcelMacro() 

 Dim xlApp 
 Dim xlBook 

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\internal.company.com\River_Automated.xlsm", 0, True) 
 xlApp.Run "Update"

 xlBook.Save
 xlBook.Close
 xlApp.Quit 

 Set xlBook = Nothing 
 Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

*Some side notes that may be helpful:*

After running VBScript I got this message that:

> Resume.xlsw already exists. Do you want to replace it?

I added lines that create a text file right before `End Sub` and it creates it. So, it runs the macro but does not save the workbook.

Comment: First, remove the `On Error Resume Next` , as we want to debug where the error occurs. Also, is it running the "Upadate" `Sub`, but not saving with `xlBook.Save` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I commented it out. But wanted to give you the original code. That's the weird part. Once it asked me that `Resume.xlsw` is already exist. Do you want to replace it. But Only once. I know it runs the `Sub` as I just added a line write before `End Sub` which makes a text file. And the text file is created. I will add this to the body of the question as well.

Comment: Try `Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\internal.company.com\River_Automated.xlsm", 0, False) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\internal.company.com\River_Automated.xlsm", 0, True)
```

Is causing the file to be opened in `ReadOnly` mode. The third argument of the [`Open` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) determines whether to open the file in `ReadOnly` mode if `True`, or otherwise `False`.

> ReadOnly | Optional | Variant | True to open the workbook in read-only mode.

The solution would be either to open the file in `ReadOnly = False` via:

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\internal.company.com\River_Automated.xlsm", 0, False)
```

Or, to check if the file is `ReadOnly` and if so, save it as something else.

```
If Not xlBook.ReadOnly Then
    xlBook.Save

Else
    xlBook.SaveAs ... '### Modify as needed
End If
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit 

Set xlBook = Nothing 
Set xlApp = Nothing
```